# Django: model doesn't create from models form

Tags: django

I try to create new object from model form, but objects isn't saved.

**models.py**

```
class VideoFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="video/", validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

**forms.py**

```
class VideoCreateForm(ModelForm): 

    class Meta:
        model = VideoFile
        fields = ['name', 'file']
```

**views.py**

```
def add_video(request):    

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VideoCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            messages.success(request, "saved") 
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'No success!.')            
        return redirect('vtv:video') 
    else:
        form = VideoCreateForm()
    return render(request, "vtv/video_add.html", {'form': form})
```

**templates.html**

```
<h3>Add new video</h3>
<form method = "post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You should only return the redirect if the form is valid - otherwise you will never see the errors when the form is invalid

Comment: I added block else with error messages, but the function works fine, the execution of the redirect as it should, but not saved

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code

Comment: yes I did it...

Comment: Please put the `return redirect('vtv:video')` statement at the end of the `form.is_valid()` block. You should not be redirecting unless the form is valid

Comment: I get an error This field is required for name field

Comment: Please show your template.

Comment: @Alasdair, I added template file

Comment: You are missing `enctype` in the form.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks!